# Is it possible to recover this LUKS-encrypted SD card?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, luks

I have a large size SD card that was encrypted with LUKS using the GNOME Disk Utility running on Ubuntu. I had some cherished photos on it. I've managed to accidentally format the SD card and wish to know if there is some way to recover it.

I formatted it with the quick formatting option, meaning that the SD card was not overwritten with zeros.

I have the passcode that was used to decrypt the SD card. Asking ChatGPT for help suggested that a backup of something called the LUKS header would help. I did not make such a backup myself. However, the SD card was decrypted and mounted using a computer with Ubuntu and that computer has not been rebooted since then. The same computer was also the one to initially format the SD card with LUKS.

Is it possible that this computer has a backup of this LUKS header? Is there some other approach I could try. Feeling a bit heartbroken here and would very much appreciate more information or guidance.

(I'm aware that a backup should have existed. This was not possible due to a lack of funds.)